# Button that takes me to a new UIViewController based on the content of a TextField not working

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make a button take me to a new UIViewController based on the content of a textField, but when I run it and hit the button (with the right condition in the text field to take me to the new UIViewController), the screen blacks out. This is what I wrote in my .h and .m files. Can anyone help me (Im using storyboards)

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)boton:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *texto;
@end
```

---

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"


@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize texto;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)boton:(id)sender {
    if ([texto.text isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        ViewController2 *vc1=[[ViewController2 alloc]init];
        [self presentViewController:vc1 animated:YES completion:nil];

    }


}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say the screen is blacking out, I expect your viewController is getting initialised without a view.

To initialise with a view hierarchy from a xib(nib) file:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
```

where `nibName` can be `nil` if it shares it's name with the View Controller, and `nibBundle` can be `nil` it the nib is in the main bundle.

i.e....

```
    ViewController2 *vc2;
    vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil 
                                            bundle:nil];
```

where the xib file is named `ViewController2.xib`

To initialise from a storyboard:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;

    vc2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
```

(you need to set up a viewController in storyboard and give it a matching identifier)

To initialise with neither storyboard or xib, you should override your view controller's `- (void)loadView`, create a view and assign it to `self.view`.

*Update*

In answer to your comment - the `UIStoryboard...` and `ViewController2 *vc2= ...` code would go into your button code (in your case it you would replace / adapt the line containing `vc1=...`. It would look like this:

```
- (IBAction)boton:(id)sender {
    if ([texto.text isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        ViewController2 *vc2;
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
         vc2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
        [self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

You will need to have created a storyboard scene in your storyboard with a viewController whose custom class is `ViewController2` and identifier is  `"ViewController2"`. The identifier name is arbitrary, but must match the identifier string you use in your code.

As you are using storyboards, an alternative way to do this is to create a modal segue from the 'ViewController' scene to a 'ViewController2' scene, give it an identifier, and use `performSegueWithIdentifier` in your button method.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. As you mention, I don't think he should be calling `init` on his `ViewController2`.

Comment: thank you for your answer!, I'm using storyboards, according to what you said, where should I put UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;

    vc2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

Comment: is there any problem if you gave me your email address?

Comment: @SebastianColmenares - see my updated answer. I would rather not hand you my email address as I would prefer you ask your questions - and we provide answers - in public, where it may benefit others. If I have answered _this_ question well enough, you should tick the answer to mark it as accepted.